# Get children inside a controller to display on twig template

Tags: symfony, doctrine, twig, hierarchy

I've I'm trying to build a page which collects together all of the pages on a site and displays them along with their children (if they have any).

So far I've managed to make it loop through all of the top level pages and display them, however I'm getting some difficulty in making it display the child pages in the right place. It seems that I can either retrieve them but have them appear at the end or not retreive them at all.

I would need it to look like this:

```
<div id="parent" class="guide-item">
    <h2>Parent</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p><p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
    <div id="child" class="guide-item">
        <h2>Child</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p><p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my controller (including my attempt at getting it to loop through the children:

```
// Render pages from database
public function sectorAction($sector)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $pages = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('acmeStyleGuideBundle:pageSector')
    ->findBySectorJoinedToUrlTopLevel($sector);

    if (!$pages) throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find any matching sectors');

    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        if ($page->getChildPages()) {
            $children = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('acmeStyleGuideBundle:pageContent')
                ->findBySectorAndParent($sector, $page->getPageUrl());
        }
    }

    return $this->render(
        'acmeStyleGuideBundle:Page:pages.html.twig', 
        array(
            'Pages' => $pages,
            'Children' => $children,
            'header' => $sector
        )
    );
}
```

Here are the relavent repositories:

```
public function findBySectorJoinedToUrlTopLevel($sector)
{
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('
            SELECT p, s FROM acmeStyleGuideBundle:PageContent p
            JOIN p.pageSector s
            LEFT JOIN p.pageTypes t
            WHERE s.sectorName = :sector
            AND t.typeName != :type
            AND p.parentPage IS NULL'
        )
        ->setParameter('type', 'Section Headers')
        ->setParameter('sector', $sector);

    try {
        return $query->getResult();
    } catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
        return null;
    }
}

    public function findBySectorAndParent($sector, $pageParent)
{
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('
            SELECT p, s, c FROM acmeStyleGuideBundle:PageContent p
            JOIN p.pageSector s
            LEFT JOIN p.pageTypes t
            LEFT JOIN p.parentPage c
            WHERE s.sectorName = :sector
            AND p.pageUrl = :parent
            AND t.typeName != :type'
        )
        ->setParameter('sector', $sector)
        ->setParameter('parent', $pageParent)
        ->setParameter('type', 'Section Headers');

    try {
        return $query->getResult();
    } catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And here is my twig template where I want to output the code:

```
{% extends 'acmeStyleGuideBundle::landing.html.twig' %}
{% block definition %}
    <article class="js-load pageLoad">
        <h1>
            {% if header is defined %}
                {{ header | title }}
            {% else %}
                {{ Pages[0].pageName }}
            {% endif %}
        </h1>
        {% for pe in Pages %}
            <div id="{{ pe.pageUrl | lower}}" class="guide-item">
                <h2>{{ pe.pageName }}</h2>
                {{ pe.richText | raw }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </article>
{% endblock %}
```

I thought that I might hae been able to loop through the children in the controller and then apply it to the twig template as 'children' instead of 'pages' but that didn't seem to work as the following code just constantly repeated the last element in the database which WASN'T a child page.:

```
{% for ce in Children %}
    <div class="childPage">
        <div id="{{ ce.pageUrl | lower}}" class="guide-item">
            <h2>{{ ce.pageName }}</h2>
            {{ ce.richText | raw }}
            <div class="explanation">
                <div class="card active">
                    <h3>Example</h3>
                    {# ce.example | raw#}
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <h3>Code Example</h3>
                    <pre name="code" class="{#ce.lang#}">{# ce.example #}</pre>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I've been looking at this problem for a while now so I probably can no longer see the wood for the trees so feel free to pull my code to pieces. I'm a learner at symfony/twig/doctrine anyway so I'll gladly take any feedback you care to give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution.

Instead of trying to do everything in one controller and template, I created a new template called `childpages.html.twig` and put in this code:

```
{% for pe in Pages %}
        <div id="{{ pe.pageUrl | lower}}" class="guide-item child">
            <h2>{{ pe.pageName }}</h2>
            {{ pe.richText | raw }}
            {{ render(controller('acmeStyleGuideBundle:Page:findCodeExamples', { 'pageParent': pe.codeExample })) }}
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I then wrote a new controller:

```
    // Render children from database (Similar to showSubAction but without the $pageUrl requirement)
    public function findChildrenAction($pageParent, $sector)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $pages = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('acmeStyleGuideBundle:PageSector')
        ->findBySectorJoinedToParent($sector, $pageParent);
        return $this->render(
            'acmeStyleGuideBundle:Page:childPages.html.twig', 
            array(
                'Pages' => $pages,
                'sector' => $sector
            )
        );
    }
```

and referenced it in the place I needed it to appear in my original template:

```
{{ 
    render(controller('acmeStyleGuideBundle:Page:findChildren', { 
        'pageParent': pe.id, 
        'sector': 'residential'
    }))
}}
```

Not sure if it's the most elegant solution but it worked.